# How to prepare schema for csv files with varying schema in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which reads input csv file and load it to big query. The challenge now is I can get csv files with varying schema (not at the end, the order can change anywhere) , how to process the file by reading the header record and prepare schema and insert null/default values for the columns that are not present in input.

Comment: What are the errors that you are running into? I'm not sure what you mean by varying schema. Do the column types change by row? If so, Bigquery does not support that. If you mean that there should be null values, by default, if a value doesn't exist in a column in a csv file, it should include it as a NULL.

Comment: What I mean by varying schema is like I can get 30 columns in one file and 50 columns in next file. The program should be able to load the data based on column name and not by delimiter. The 20 missing columns in second file should be created and loaded with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that --schema_update_option is set to ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION and the schema of the new table is specified for example

```
bq --project_id <project_id> load --source_format=CSV --schema_update_option ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION <dataset_id>.<table_id> <data> new_col:STRING,new_col2:STRING
```

Depending on the original table schema, you might need to use `--schema_update_option ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION` which relaxes required fields to nullable.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data

Comment: Does this option work with cloud function too ? I tried adding this parameter in my cloud function but dint work. Please provide some code samples if you have. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to run?